# How to test the tps of the private ETH blockchain?

Tags: performance, blockchain, ethereum

I  deploy the private ETH blockchain on my laptop, and I want to know how many transactions per second(tps) of it.

Are there some tools to test tps of the blockchain system?

Comment: Short answer is that there are no load testing tools for private blockchains and you need to write your own testing scripts.

Answer (score 1):

The performance of the blockchain in tps depends on many conditions - both the mining settings of the blockchain itself and the kind of the transactions being executed. Mining settings include, for example, the block generation frequency and the gas limit per block. The "weight" of transactions can also be different - the "heaviest" are transactions for creating smart contracts, the "lightest" are simple Еther transfer transactions.

The easiest way to check is to start generating transactions of a certain type with some frequency and track how many of them will end up in blocks. Since the time for sending a transaction at a node is usually quite long, it is better to create a stream of transactions from several nodes to create a significant load.

The exact mechanism for generating transactions depends on which software platform you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

My team and I created [pandoras-box](https://github.com/madz-lab/pandoras-box) , a command-line interface tool for running stress tests on Ethereum-compatible blockchain networks. We designed it to be an essential tool for Ethereum client developers looking to test the performance of their blockchain under high load.

> *Key Features:*
>
> - Batch transactions to make stress testing easier to orchestrate
> - Multiple stress testing modes: EOA, ERC20, and ERC721
> - Distributed transaction stress testing through subaccounts
> - Automatic subaccount fund top-up
> - Detailed statistics calculation
> - Output cycle run results to a file
>
> *Usage Example:*
>
> To run a stress test with pandoras-box, install it using npm or yarn:
>
> `npm install -g pandoras-box`
>
> Then, run the stress test by specifying the options for the test:
>
> `pandoras-box -url http://127.0.0.1:10002 -m "erupt oven loud noise rug proof sunset gas table era dizzy vault" -t 100 -b 5000 -o ./myOutput.json`
>
> For any stress test run, there need to be funds on a specific address.
> The address that is in charge of funds distribution to subaccounts is
> the first address with index 0 in the specified mnemonic. Make sure
> this address has an appropriate amount of funds before running the
> stress test

Documentation: https://docs.madz-lab.com/pandoras-box/

GitHub: https://github.com/madz-lab/pandoras-box